# Tenant Multi tenancy Laravel Unit Testing issue

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant, multi-database

Here is the test case that i created for category testing. I am getting 404 on this route while i have correctly configured the tenant test case and this route is exist on subdomain that was created on chrome browser.

```
public function test_example()
{
    $response = $this->call('GET', '/categories/6/edit');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode(),$response->exception->getMessage());
}
```

My TestCase.php

```
  protected $tenancy = false;

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    if ($this->tenancy) {
        $this->initializeTenancy();
    }
}

public function initializeTenancy()
{
    $tenant = Tenant::create();
    tenancy()->initialize($tenant);
}
```

Documentation I am following
https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/testing

Result:
I want 302 response means redirect to login code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this piece of code can help you

https://github.com/archtechx/tenancy/issues/635#issuecomment-939226522

```
    tenancy()->initialize($tenant);
    URL::forceRootUrl('http://' . $tenant->domains[0]['domain']);
```